# Save plain text files with other extension than .txt

Tags: macos, google-chrome

When I open a plain text file in chrome and choose save as, how can I change the extension in the "save as" dialog in Chrome?

For example consider this file: https://raw.github.com/filmgirl/TextMate-Themes/master/Tubster.tmTheme

When I try to save that file I get this dialog:
[image]

Changing the text in the textfield to the following does not work:

```
Tubster.tmTheme    ->  Tubster.tmTheme.txt
"Tubster.tmTheme"  ->  "Tubster.tmTheme".txt
```

Is there a way of saving this as `Tubster.tmTheme`?

I'm using Mac OS, so this may only be a problem on that OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expand the dialog by clicking the triangle after the "Save As" textfield.

Then if you try to save the file as `Tubster.tmTheme`, Chrome will give you a dialog, where you can use the `.tmTheme` extension.

[image]